# $\text{Aut}(G) \cong \text{Out}(G)$ when $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I would appreciate if you could please evaluate my proof and point out any mistakes I made.

**Proof:**

Define a homomorphism $\Phi: \text{Aut}(G)\to \text{Out}(G)$, such that all elements of $\text{Out}(G) \leq \text{Aut}(G)$ are sent to $\text{Out}(G)$ (identically), and all elements of $\text{Inn}(G) \leq \text{Aut}(G)$ are sent to $1$. Thus $\Phi$ is surjective. Now let $\phi_a$ be an element of $\text{Inn}(G)$. Then $\phi_a(g) = aga^{-1}=aa^{-1}g=g \implies \phi_a = id_G \implies \text{Inn}(G)=\{id_G\}$. This implies that $\ker(\Phi)$ is empty, and hence $\Phi$ is injective. Therefore, $\Phi$ is an isomoprhism $\implies$ $\text{Aut}(G)\cong \text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: How are you defining $Out(G)$? If it is the subset of $Aut(G)$ consisting of the outer (non-inner) automorphisms, then $Out(G)$ is not a subgroup of $Aut(G)$. The usual definition is $Out(G) = Aut(G)/Inn(G)$, and that is also not a subgroup of $Aut(G)$. So your definition of $\Phi$ doesn't make sense. Perhaps more straightforward: note that if $G$ is abelian, then $Inn(G)$ is trivial (why?)

Comment: You shouldn't define your homomorphism the way you did. The map you want is the quotient map $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \to \mathrm{Aut}(G) / \mathrm{Inn}(G) = \mathrm{Out}(G)$. This is better because first of all it's a very natural definition for your context and second of all $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ is not a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, so you cannot map to $\mathrm{Out}(G) "identically" like you just did. You can map it "canonically" however, using the canonical projection map, which is already given to you.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, I noted this in my proof above, but I thought that would be too easy.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thanks for pointing out that $Out(G)$ is not a subgroup of $Aut(G)$. I'm wondering, however, if $\Phi$ could be defined in such a way as to map all elements of $Out(G) \subseteq Aut(G)$ to $Aut(G)$?

Comment: @sequence : Sometimes math is easy and you don't need to make it harder than it has to be. 

In the mean time, in your computation of the kernel you should be more careful. The kernel it certainly not empty since it contains the inner automorphism group of $G$, which in particular contains the identity element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. What you need to show is that this is the only element of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ in the kernel, which is what you did. But it doesn't prove that your map is the identity, it proves that it is an isomorphism. $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is not a subset of $\mathrm{Out}(G)$..

Comment: @sequence : The reason why $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ is not a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is because it's not even a subset of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof does not seem to be true because as mentioned in comments $Out(G)$ is not even a subset of $Aut(G)$ in general. On the other hand, the proof of your result is very obvious. Indeed $Out(G)$ is just defined to be $Aut(G) / Inn(G)$. You proved that $Inn(G)  = 1$. So  we have $Aut(G) = Out(G)$.